# Showing company name in address bar requires SSL EV certificate, or OV also OK?

Tags: https, security-certificate, site-verification, certificate-generation

I remember in the past I had to buy an SSL EV certificate (which are much more expensive than regular SSL certificates) to get the company name displaying next to the green lock in the address bar.

I am about to renew a few certificates and I now see many SSL issuers also offer 'SSL OV' (Organization Validation) certificates.

The description says "light business authentication". Would that also show the company name in the address bar?

Note that I don't actually care about verification or authentication or insurance whatsoever. Don't need wildcard either. I just want SSL with the company name in the address bar.

Comment: Have a look at: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35076/how-does-an-end-user-differentiate-between-ov-and-dv-certificates and https://blog.movingtohttps.com/whats-the-difference-between-dv-ov-ev-ssl-certificates-9e07ea1baa1 . The company name should be visible, yes. But that should be a question easily answered by the company providing you the certificates. They could even provide a short term one for you to test.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks. If I understand that first link correctly, the company info is only visible in the certificate details, if the user explicitly clicks on it (which nobody ever does). Unfortunately, the company name does not seem to appear in the address bar, as it does with EV certificates.

Comment: Yes, quite arbitrarily, browsers favor EV certificates.

Comment: See also: [Should we get an EV Certificate?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/should-we-get-an-ev-certificate) and [How do I show the company name in the browser address bar next to the SSL padlock?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/114007/how-do-i-show-the-company-name-in-the-browser-address-bar-next-to-the-ssl-padloc)

Answer (score 1):

Only the EV = Extended Validation certificates give you the *green bar*.

It looks different, though, in each browser, these are just examples:

[image: green bar in different browsers]

None of the OV / DV give it to you.

The OV certificates just contain company information in it, are worth in my opinion only to State authorities.

Comment: This may soon go away: https://techdows.com/2019/08/chrome-and-firefox-browsers-to-remove-extended-validation-ev-certificate-indicators-from-url-bar.html.  For example "Starting Firefox 70 browser will show normal lock icon for EV certificates."  No more special green bar or company name...