# How do I show the company name in the browser address bar next to the SSL padlock?

Tags: https

I have an SSL certificate for my website.

I want to show the name, owner, owner unit in the browser address bar just like Github has.

See the red rectangle:
[image]

How can I set that?

Answer (score 3):

That isn't a CNAME shown in the address bar. It is the official company name from an extended verification (EV) certificate. If you get one of those certificates browsers always show the company name from them.

See [Should we get an EV Certificate?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/should-we-get-an-ev-certificate)   The certificates typically cost a lot more and require more paperwork to obtain.

Answer (score 1):

Extended Validation Certificate is a type of SSL, which only used to display verified company name along with country ID in the browser address bar.

EV (Extended Validation) issued through a manual verification process, and a certificate authority accomplishes this task. That is why it is a bit costlier than other SSL Certificate.

The Extended Validation Certificate issued to the following types of companies.

1. Government Agencies
2. Corporations
3. General Partnerships
4. Unincorporated Associations
5. Sole Proprietorships

If your business comes under above-listed company types. Then you can apply for the Extended Validation Certificate. This process required proof of the official document of your business existence, and it takes approx 7 to 10 day for verification.

You need to provide below information.

1. Required verified business Phone number and it should be listed in authorised telephones records.
2. Date of registration/incorporation details
3. Registered address or registered agent’s address of the organisation records
4. Lawyer Opinion Letter
5. Accountant Opinion Letter

Comment: This is the second time you recommended this specific SSL vendor in one of your answers here.   Please don't do so again.    Your answer is otherwise very good, however recommendations from new users are likely to be self promotion or spam.   That is against our guidelines and if it happens again, you will be suspended from this site.  See https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/behavior