# EV SSL with a static resource server

Tags: https

We have the domain:

```
 www.scirra.com
```

Which we are going through the process of obtaining an EV SSL certificate for.  The site makes use of our static domain to server CSS/images etc.  It has 4 subdomains:

```
static1.scirra.net
static2.scirra.net
static3.scirra.net
static4.scirra.net
```

To stop security warnings when loading static resources from https://www.scirra.com I'm guessing we need an SSL certificate for the static server.

1. I'm guessing the .net certificate doesn't need to be EV
2. I'm assuming the .net certificate doesn't have to be the same provider?

Amateur question I know but just want to check before we spend money on a cheap wildcard certificate for the static server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you need a certificate to stop warnings (though different browsers have different sorts of warnings, some are almost unnoticeable).

1. Yes, it doesn't need to be EV - see [What are the benefits of a more expensive SSL certificate?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3836/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-more-expensive-ssl-certificate)
2. Yes, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6):

You are correct on both counts. The .net certificate doesn't have to be an EV certificate, and doesn't have to be from the same provider.

Paypal does exactly what you want to do.

1. https://www.paypal.com/ has an EV certificate from Verisign
2. Static content is loaded from https://www.paypalobjects.com/, which is signed by Akamai and isn't an EV certificate.